# Specific noqa doesn't seem work (PyCharm)?

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

In both cases:

```
print("test")    
import cmprsk.cmprsk as cmprsk  # noqa: E402
a = cmprsk.import_R
```

[image]

and

```
print("test")
import cmprsk.cmprsk as cmprsk  # noqa: E501
a = cmprsk.import_R
```

[image]

I don't have the warning `PEP 8: E402 module level import not at top of file`.

I should, however, have the warning in the second case.

I do have the warning when I don't specify the # noqa: Exxx tag. Which is expected.
[image]

I'm using Python 3.10.2 and PyCharm:

```
PyCharm 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-222.4345.23, built on October 10, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2030M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
me.lensvol.blackconnect (0.5.0)
com.chesterccw.excelreader (2022.8.1-203.222)
```

The behaviour I expect is supposed to be working, here is an example from the official blog of JetBrains (https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2020/02/pycharm-2020-1-eap-4/):
[image]

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the interaction between `import` and `# noqa`, it happens to me too. Feel free to [submit a bug report](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html) with Jetbrains if you like.

Comment: Unfortunately Jetbrains issue report is not very responsive :/ Last one I reported (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57150/PyCharm-should-report-type-ignore-comment-with-a-weak-warning?clearDraft=true&description=%0A%0APC-222.4345.23,%20JRE%2017.0.4.1%2B7-b469.62x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o.,%20OS%20Windows%2011(amd64)%20v10.0%20,%20screens%202400.0x1350.0,%205120.0x3200.0) is still not fixed even if it's kinda trivial I guess